# Windows Boot Manager no aparece en las entradas de la BIOS

Tags: windows

Estaba tratando de instalar Windows 7 en otro disco duro que tengo insertado en mi computadora.

Resulta que cuando fui a arrancar el Windows 11 que tengo insertado en mi disco duro principal, me olvide de desconectar el otro disco, y se mezclaron los dos Windows Boot Manager.

En el disco principal tengo un dualboot entre VanillaOS (Linux) y Windows 11. Ahora solo puedo acceder a Linux por que no se muestra la entrada de Windows Boot Manager cuando desconecto el disco que tiene Windows 7. Cuando lo conecto se muestra, pero cuando lo trato iniciar, se me inicia el Windows 7. No lo puedo iniciar desde GRUB por que no habia detectado la entrada de Windows Boot Manager, y entonces lo tenia que iniciar desde el menu de arranque de la BIOS.

Solo para un poco de informacion, mi placa madre es una Gigabyte GA-B75M-HD3.

¿Alguna solucion?

(Edit: Tampoco funciona desconectando y volviendo a conectar el disco principal)

Comment: Bienvenido. Creo que este no es el sitio para preguntas sobre BIOS y hardware. Tal vez deberías ir a [su].

Comment: Deberías arreglar el bootloader. Por empezar deberías preguntarte cuál quieres usar, si el Windows Boot Manager o GRUB. Luego averiguar cómo arreglarlo o de no ser posible, reinstalarlo.

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre a mi. 
Ves a las propiedades del sistema > configuración avanzada del sistema. Debe salirte algo como "Inicio y recuperación" y en la ventanita que se abre debe haber un desplegable que indica el SO que quieres iniciar (deberían salir los dos windows) y luego un check que dice "Mostrar la lista de sistemas operativos por x segundos". Yo creo que si en el windows que sí puedes entrar configuras eso correctamente, deberías poder luego hacer lo que quieres. 
Alternativamente: desde cmd como admin > diskpart y luego > bootrec /fixboot